# В каких случаях function declaration может не иметь имени?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

Когда `function declaration` не возвращается, то запись без имени вызывает ошибку - **Function statements require a function name**.

```
function func(a) {
  console.log(a);
  function () { //Function statements require a function name
    a++;
  }
}
```

Но такой код ошибки не вызывает:

```
function func(a) {
  console.log(a);
  return function () { //нет ошибки
    a++;
  }
}
```

Выходит, что `function declaration` может быть без имени только в том случае, если функция возвращается?

Comment: Во втором примере уже не function declaration, а function exresson, которое не требует имени.

Comment: всегда улыбают ваши вопросы. Даже никогда таким не задавался))

Comment: @entithat хах) ну это не суть важно, просто было интересно)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty а разве `function expression` это не только тогда, когда мы в переменную кладем ссылку на функцию? Ну типа такого: `var foo = function() {}`

Comment: Нет. Expression это всегда где не может быть statement. Например в IIFE тоже нет никакого присваивания

Comment: Можно подробнее тут посмотреть примеры: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function vs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: @Alexey Ten понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни в каком. Function declaration всегда с именем.

Comment: не совсем так...

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии со [спецификацией](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-FunctionDeclaration) имя у Function declaration может отсутствовать при дефолтном экспорте.

Например:

```
export default function () {
}
```

Comment: Эм.. А почему это не function expression?

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что именно в этом случае это будет declaration :) там посмотри по ссылке идет как раз синтаксис для declaration

Comment: Прикольно. И странно.